# identifier "LgameName" is undefined with _T

Tags: c++

I am writing a application and seem to come to a problem. I have used _T Before but i am getting a weird problem, here is my code

```
char gameName[] = "gamedll_x64_rwdi.dll";   
DWORD gameBaseAddress = GetModuleBaseAddress(_T(gameName), pID);
```

The error says identifier "LgameName" is undefined.
What i noticed is the name is gameName. not LgameName....

I also did include #include tchar.h so this isnt the problem here.... Thank you for anyone that wants to help... This is in a cmd prompt c++ application

Comment: `_T` is a preprocessor macro that is used only for *literals* like `_T("gamedll_x64_rwdi.dll")` you cannot pass it a `char[]` variable.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: The `_T` macro can only be used with string literals.